# whose view is not in the window hierarchy! (performSegue storyboard)

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to call the segue from class with the following code

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"inicio" sender:self];
```

what's wrong?

Comment: I assume it's complaining about whatever class contains that line.  Is it a view controller?  Has it been pushed or presented?

Comment: @Developer2012 could you please edit your post and provide more details to explain what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

the other view was not dismissed. Now, It works!